# Declaring delegate static works but weak does not

Tags: swift, delegates

Here's my example usage of delegate. The code passes a message from one view to other view controller.  My code for the weak `delegate`:

Send message View Controller which sends message:

```
protocol SendMessageDelegate: AnyObject {
    func message(text: String)
}
```

I have also used UICollectionViewDelegate, NSFetchedControllerDelegate

```
final class SendMessageController: UIViewController {     
    weak var delegate: SendMessageDelegate?  

    @objc func button() {
        sendMessage()  
    }

    func sendMessage() {
       let message = “Hello World”
       delegate?.message(text: message)
    }
}
```

Show Message View Controller which receives message:

```
final class ShowMessageController: UIViewController,SendMessageDelegate {
     
    let sendMessageController = SendMessageController() 
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sendMessageController.delegate = self
    }
    
    func message(text: String) {
        print(“The message is:\(text)”)          
    }       
}
```

Comment: There are many problems with your code. But let's start by asking where you create and use an instance of your `SendMessageController` class. Please update your question with that code.

Comment: I have edited code that uses weak, with little change static var works. Thank you.

Comment: Is `SendMessageController` declared in a storyboard? If yes, the instance you've created is not the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: @vadian: I did all programmatically, without using storyboard.

Comment: Let's check a few things: In `delegate?.message(text: message)`, is `delegate` `nil`? In `ShowMessageController`, you don't do any other `SendMessageController()`? How do you show it?

Comment: @Larme

`func message(text: String) {
        print(“The message is:\(text)”)          
    }`

 I tried checking weather delegate works or not by print function , and no output is shown in terminal.

Comment: ShowMessageController is not implementing the SendMessageDelegate protocol. Doing this should solve your problem.

Comment: Let's debug: `print("Delegate in sendMessage: \(delegate)")`. I guess it's nil. Add also, print("self: \(self)"). When you do `sendMessageController.delegate = self`, add print("SendMessageVC: \(sendMessageController")`  And share the outputs. And don't you have a warning on `sendMessageController.delegate = self` as it's not conforming to the delegate?)

Comment: `print("Delegate in sendMessage: \(delegate)"`
This printed nil. 

`print("self: (self)")`
This printed memory address of controller

`print("SendMessageVC: (sendMessageController")`
This too printed memory address of controller 

**warning on sendMessageController.delegate = self **

I didn't use warning here..

Comment: I think problem lies by creating new instance 
`let sendMessageController = SendMessageController()`

I am trying to solve this by looking at this post:
[link](http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/)

Comment: Is it the same memory address? Not warning, indeed but there wasn't `SendMessageDelegat ` In `UIViewController, SendMessageDelegate` previously.

Comment: @Larme: No both address are different. 
Yes, I added here later, but my code has.

Comment: So it's indeed an issue of wrong instances. Is there another place where you do `SendMessageDelegate()` which is short of `SendMessageDelegate.init()` or other init call? That's where lies your issue. But it's missing code, so we can't guess where.

Comment: @Larme: There was another instance of SendMessageController() from the button where the SendMessage view is called. I removed that and boom it did worked. Thank you Larme, you are  savior for today. 

SendMessageController()